# What is this pipe beneath my tankless water heater?

Tags: water-tank, tankless

While watching videos about draining tankless water heaters, I noticed none seem to have this beige pipe with odd silver cab at the end. Does anyone know what this is and its purpose?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is what we call a "pop off", or pressure relief valve. If the water pressure gets too high, that valve will open and drain into your waste water system. Its there so your tank, or hot water system, does not blow up due to getting too hot.

Comment: When draining a tankless heater, do I need to do anything special w.r.t. the pop off valve.

Comment: @Craig, No, you don't need to do anything with the pressure relief valve. It's simply a safety device.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that's the pressure relief valve. Where does the plastic pipe go to

Comment: It goes into the wall